# How is Electromagnetic segmented-capacitor propulsion system even possible?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image: schema]

The alleged invention - patent [US10006446B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US10006446B2/) - suggest allowing the creation of lifting force (4) on electrically charged rotating plate when the magnetic flux is turned on and directed towards the center of the rotation axis.

But I beg to differ.

I understand that while the rotating upper plate will be pushed up, it will also slow down, and the exact opposing force (skewed) will act on the charged plate.
So the whole model will try to rip apart.

Can you please tell me how will this model work in reality?

Comment: This is not an answer because I will not analyze the details of the device, but it clearly cannot work, or it will otherwise be a perpetum mobile

Comment: @Wolphramjonny why perpetum mobile? If the coils were pushed outside and the plate upside then what's perpetual about it?

Comment: that is what I understood by reading the patent description, but I might have misinterpreted it. I will check it more carefully later